# env-entry in ejb-jar.xml not being injected with @Resource when deployed inside WAR file

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1, ejb-jar.xml

I have a maven web application that has a dependency on an EJB project.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>soar-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

In the EJB project there I've added an `env-entry` in the `ejb-jar.xml` as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     version = "3.1"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <env-entry>
                <description>Config file</description>
                <env-entry-name>configFileLocation</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>dropbox-config.properties</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

I've tested the EJB project, using arquillian, and I am able to inject this value using `@Resource` 
as such:
    @Resource(name = "configFileLocation")
    private String configFile;

Now, when I build the .war with the ejb dependency, I get a .war with my EJB project as a .jar inside `WEB-INF\lib`.  Within this EJB project (i.e. inside the .jar)  the `ejb-jar.xml` file is in the proper  `META-INF` directory.

BUT now, when I deploy to the server the `@Resource` injection never works. The `String` is always `null`. According to what I have read I have the `ejb-jar.xml` in the correct location, both within the EJB project and within the .war that maven produces.

Would someone have an idea of what I've configured incorrectly?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Modified the session element to

```
<session>
        <description>An EJB that loads configuration from a file</description>
        <display-name>ConfigurationProducer</display-name>
        <ejb-name>ConfigurationProducer</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.trf.util.DropboxConfigFileProducer</ejb-class>
        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
        <env-entry>
            <description>Location of the config file</description>
            <env-entry-name>configFileLocation</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>dropbox-config.properties</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
    </session>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by modifying the dependency for the `ejb` project in `pom.xml` to be `provided` and then wrapping the `war` and `ejb` projects into an `ear` project. `pom.xml` of the web archive now looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>soar-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then in the `ear` project's `pom.xml` we have this:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>soar-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>soar-war</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`@Resource` injection is now working on the `env-entries` in the `ejb`'s `ejb-jar.xml` when I deploy to the server from the `ear` project !

Answer (score 0):

The *session* element of your *ejb-jar.xml* doesn't contain the *ejb-name* property, try to put one with the name matching the bean interface name. I've edited your answer to show you an example.

Comment: Remigo, I've added the ejb-name element to the session element and the resource is still not getting injected. Still works when I test the ejb  project by itself.